# The first multi-syllabic positive integer

Tags: list-of-languages, numbers

*This puzzle is not about linguistics, but I do not see a better place for this question.*

Suppose N(L) is the first multi-syllabic positive integer in the given language L.
So

- N(Russian) = N(Hebrew) = 1,
- N(Turkish) = 2,
- N(German) = N(English) = 7, and
- N(French) = 14.

Do you know a language with N>14?

Comment: Not sure this is a good place for this kind of question, even if it theoretically has a unique answer, but isn't that wrong for Chechen anyway? https://www.omniglot.com/language/numbers/chechen.htm By your definition, N(Chechen) seems to be 10.

Comment: @jogloran Did you mean 11? I don’t know Chechen, but _итт_ ‘ten’ looks monosyllabic to me (based on the fact that Wikipedia gives the name of the language as _Нохчийн мотт_, in which the last word is /muɔt/), whereas _цхьайтта_ ‘eleven’ must be disyllabic. Whether it’s 10 or 11, French would be an obvious candidate, with the first polysyllabic numeral being _quatorze_ ‘fourteen’ (if you allow _quatre_ as just /katʀ/ in French, rather than /ˈkatʀə/).

Comment: Sorry, I did mean 11 (first polysyllabic vs. last monosyllabic)...

Comment: Thank you I looked at cardinal numbers --- my mistake. I will correct the question.

Comment: N(Turkish) = 2, it's _iki_ with ‘one’ being _bir_.

Comment: Just as an interesting aside, if you did it the other way around (last monosyllabic instead of first polysyllabic), you would have languages like [Greenlandic](https://www.omniglot.com/language/numbers/greenlandic.htm) that wouldn’t qualify at all, since _every_ number in the language has at least two syllables.

Comment: Is French *quatre*, pronounced carefully and with emphasis, not a word with two syllables? Online pronunciation samples vary -- [LEO](https://dict.leo.org/franz%C3%B6sisch-deutsch/quatre) is clearly bi-syllabic, while [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/File:Fr-quatre.ogg) is on the edge for me. Regional and individual differences probably make a definite answer impossible.

Answer (score 5):

You can perhaps answer this question to some degree of certainty using this defunct resource, preserved by the Internet Archive: [Numeral Systems of the World's Languages](https://web.archive.org/web/20161221000001/https://mpi-lingweb.shh.mpg.de/numeral/). It contains IPA transcriptions for [each included language](https://web.archive.org/web/20160310020207/https://mpi-lingweb.shh.mpg.de/numeral/Awadhi.htm), although [many of the pages](https://mpi-lingweb.shh.mpg.de/numeral/Even.htm) were not chosen for preservation by the Internet Archive.